# Manage image on camera surface view. How to get left and right border?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

first I thought this is a trival thing but when I've started to code I found that it is not so easy. So let me start. I have a `SurfaceView` in which I'm displaying preview from my camera On top of that I want to put an `ImageView` and move it from max left border to max right border.

```
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I put my `ImageView` from my activity

```
    Drawable drawable  = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_compass, this.getTheme());
    objectImage = new ImageView(this);
    objectImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    objectImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

The first problem that I see is the fact that my image is not set to the left border. It is a bit to the center. So I've tried to set the margin using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` but it didn't help. Same efect.

WHen I set my animation

```
TranslateAnimation fromLeftToRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200, 0, 0);
```

It is not starting from max left border but from the position that is on the start.

So my 2 questions are:

1. how from code I can set my image to the left border of my surfaceview ?
2. if left border is represented by 0 how can I get position of right border ?